# Pasting from alternate register in windows

Tags: windows, vim

I'm working in win10 and copied some code from a stackoverflow page

```
 list(set(a) & set(b))
```

using control-c . I tried to paste this into my pycharm python code using 'P' (I'm using the ideavim plugin ), but I got 'page_text_list' instead.

```
--- Registers ---
""   page_text_list
"*   >>> list(set(a) & set(b))
"+   >>> list(set(a) & set(b))
"-   page_text_list
```

How can I paste 'list(set(a) & set(b))' into my code?

Comment: Did you read `:help p`?

Comment: @romainl That is not the correct place to look. You will find the information in `:help clipboard` instead.

Comment: @HielkeWalinga yes, that is the correct place to look as it tells you how to paste from a register, which is all the OP needs.

Comment: @romainl Knowing which register is the system clipboard register is also useful information. Maybe he just needed both places for the information.

Comment: The OP already knows which registers contains his text. All he needs is to know how to use those registers, which is explained in `:help p`. Anyway, the OP doesn't even use Vim to begin with so any pure Vim pointer will only add confusion, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use your system clipboard register.

This is `+` and `*`.

You can use like this <kbd>"+P</kbd> or <kbd>"*P</kbd>.